# Using MySQL with Ejabberd

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ejabberd, riak

I'm trying to integrate MySQL into Ejabberd but I'm constantly facing problem with it. I'm working in AWS EC2 environment and I have 1 EC2 instance that has MySQL, Ejabberd and latest Erlang (Version 17) installed. Then I have exactly followed steps specified in this link:
https://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver
However, when I view erlang.log and ejabberd.log files, it indicates there is MySQL module missing issue:

> =CRASH REPORT==== 10-Jun-2015::06:05:28 ===   crasher:
>       initial call: application_master:init/4
>       pid: <0.41.0>
>       registered_name: []
>       exception exit: {bad_return,{{ejabberd_app,start,[normal,[]]},
>                                    {'EXIT',database_module_missing}}}
>         in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 133)
>       ancestors: [<0.40.0>]
>       messages: []
>       links: [<0.40.0>,<0.42.0>,<0.7.0>]
>       dictionary: []
>       trap_exit: true
>       status: running
>       heap_size: 610
>       stack_size: 27
>       reductions: 101   neighbours:

I have downloaded and tried out various modules but all of them have failed. For example, 
[Link from this blog post http://stefan-strigler.de/2009/01/14/ejabberd-mysql-drivers-for-debian-and-ubuntu/](http://blog.jwchat.org/download/ejabberd-mysql-20090114_1-2_all.deb)

Doesn't work at all. And when I  ./build.sh the following module:
https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules/mysql/trunk/ It creates nothing inside ebin/ folder of it.

I have done everything that is specified in this turorial: https://www.ejabberd.im/Using%20ejabberd%20with%20MySQL%20native%20driver except for the very first part (driver part). Can you please suggest me how to solve this or any alternative (easy) way to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the Erlang VM is unable to either find or access one of  mysql.beam, mysql_auth.beam, mysql_conn.beam or mysql_recv.beam.  Make sure those are all in the appropriate `ebin` directory and readable as the user ejabberd runs as.

Answer (score 0):

The post you are referring to are obsolete.

To use ejabberd with native Erlang MySQL driver, this is now very easy and quite straightforward. Only two steps are required:

1. Make sure you have an ejabberd with MySQL support enabled. Two way to have that:

   - Download a binary installer or RPM / DEB package. The needed MySQL component is included. Installer and packages can be downloaded from [ejabberd official download page](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/).
   - Build ejabberd from source and make sure it is configured with the `--enable-mysql` configure option. You can refer to ejabberd documentation for details on how to build ejabberd: [Installing ejabberd from Source Code](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#installing-ejabberd-from-source-code).
2. Create MySQL database schema. The latest version of the schema for MySQL is available here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/processone/ejabberd/master/sql/mysql.sql
3. You need to configure ejabberd to use MySQL. You first need to configure the database at the root level of the config file as described here: [ejabberd Database and LDAP Configuration](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#database-and-ldap-configuration). Once database configured, you can select on a module by module basis, which backend you want to use. For user base, you need to define the `odbc` `auth_method`. For other modules, you need to pass the option `db_type` with the value `odbc`. Here is example documentation for contact list [`mod_roster`](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modroster).